# XCode - Printing Live Values of objects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

Hi I am debugging and need to be able to check what the values of my properties within my objects are. They are strings... but I dont see the actual string itself.

I just get this here:

[image]

some advice would be nice...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below method to TrackVO class

```
- (NSString *)description{
   return @"put together your instance property values and send out";
}
```

Note:
You are overriding the method that is inherited from NSObject.
%@ and xCode-variable-view will implicitly call this description method.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger sometimes messes up the contents of variables. Try logging your strings.

```
NSLog(@"String value: %@", myString);
```

Comment: hmm even then I get just [4532:f803]

Comment: Thanks Drummer... just found exactly that out ! ;) thanks for your time